# How do I create an array from a looping val?

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have this partial piece of code that compares all text in a contenteditable div called #notes from an array created from a text document called dictionary.txt.

It loops through all the split text from #notes called splitCntEditableTxt and checks whether it matches. if matched, it creates a new span with the matched value in it.

Now, I want to create a new array by using all the matched val from the loop. So any ideas of creating that array from a loop? Here's the partial code. Thank again~!!!

```
$('#lattePool').load('dictionary.txt', function(){
    var text = $("#lattePool").text().toUpperCase();
    var words = text.split("\n");
    var dictionary = new Array();
    for(var i=0; i < words.length; i++) {
        dictionary[i] = words[i];
    };

    var contentEditableTxt = $("#notes").text();
    var splitCntEditableTxt = contentEditableTxt.replace(/([.,-=/])/g," ").split(" ");

    //alert(splitCntEditableTxt); //DEBUG

    $.each(splitCntEditableTxt,function(key,val){
        var nameFound = $.inArray(val.trim().toUpperCase(), dictionary);
        if (nameFound === -1){
        } else {
            $("#notes").append('<span class="matchedWord">'+val+'</span>');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Declare a blank array before the above code

   ```html
   var vals_array = [];
   ```
2. Push the 'val' every time it is found into that array. Change your else statement as this:

   ```html
   else {
       $("#notes").append('<span class="matchedWord">'+val+'</span>');
       vals_array.push(val);
   }
   ```
3. P.S.: Save yourself some space and change the if-else statement to this:

   ```html
   if (nameFound !== -1){
       $("#notes").append('<span class="matchedWord">'+val+'</span>');
       vals_array.push(val);
   }
   ```

Comment: Oh, it works wonderfully, thanks for the help~ very much appreciated~!! Btw, if I use !== instead of !===, I can skip the else statement?

Comment: `===` means "equal to", `!==` means "does not equal to".
You could just say If (nameFound does not equal to -1) Then (do something) instead of saying If (nameFound equals to -1) Then (do nothing) Else (do something)

Answer (score 0):

Initialize an array outside of `$.each` and then append to that array in your loop. It's a problem of scope more than anything.

If you don't know how to do what I suggested, let me know but you'll learn more if you work it out for yourself.

Comment: OK, got it. Thank you very much for your advice, because I'm just starting to learn some jquery because in the past I only use it for dynamic UI application, and for animations and effects.